# PropTypes doesn't work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am running React 16.2.0 and I am using PropTypes 15.6.1. I am using ES6 syntax and Webpack.

I am trying to make PropTypes throw a warning when I pass invalid props, but it doesn't work. This is the code:

**SimpleMessage.js**

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

class SimpleMessage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        )
    }
}

SimpleMessage.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.func
}

export default SimpleMessage
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import SimpleMessage from "./components/SimpleMessage"

window.React = React

ReactDOM.render(
    <SimpleMessage message={"Hello World"} />,
    document.getElementById("react-container")
)
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack")
var path = require("path")

process.noDeprecation = true

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets'),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env', 'stage-0', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader', {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                      plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
                    }}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader', {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                      plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
                    }}, 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            warnings: false,
            mangle: false
        })
    ]

}
```

As you might notice I am passing a string ("Hello World") but checking for a function in proptypes. I don't get any errors or warnings by proptypes, and the code runs just fine.

Comment: Try removing `window.React = React`

Comment: I tried but nothing changes

Comment: Be sure your browser console is configured to display warning level, you  may have a filter.

Comment: In "Default levels" settings Info, Warnings and Errors are already checked

Comment: Is it working if you do a `console.error('test')` in the `render()` ? Edited to error, prop-types actually throws an error my bad.

Comment: Yes I can see the test error in the console, but not prop-types error.

Comment: Last hope, rebuild prop-types package or create a new project.

Comment: None works. Could the problem be in webpack.config.js file since I am using Webpack?

Comment: Maybe, you can add it to your post, have you tried with `create-react-app` ?

Comment: I added the source code of webpack.config.js. I tried with create-react-app and it works! But I can't find out where is the problem if I don't use create-react-app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as expected :

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `message` of type `string` supplied to `SimpleMessage`, expected `function`.

Be sure to check your browser console, this is where errors are displayed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paGYjm?editors=1111

---

Also :

> You shouldn’t apply UglifyJsPlugin or DefinePlugin with 'production' value in development because they will hide useful React warnings, and make the builds much slower.

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#webpack)

Comment: Yes I know I have to check browser console. My browser doesn't show any warning for my code runned locally. I see the warning on your codepen example. Do you think it's a configuration problem of proptypes on my machine?

Comment: If you `console.error` something in your console, you see it ?

Comment: Yes. Read comments under the question to see what I tried to do.

Comment: Try setting NODE_ENV to development, I think nothing is displayed in production.

Comment: If I delete webpack.DefinePlugin { ... } it finally shows prop-types errors! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've defined `propType` as `function`, but you're sending it as a `string`.

Change the code to `message: PropTypes.string`

Comment: My problem is that PropTypes doesn't throw a warning but it should.